# WCF ServerInspectorBehavior - How to keep a header in AfterReceiveRequest to use in BeforeSendReply

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service that I have extended its behavior.

This is my code:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext) {
    if (logger.IsInfoEnabled) {

        // this is a header sent from client that I need to keep so I can return it in BeforeSendReply

        var securityToken = request.Headers.GetHeader < string > (request.Headers.FindHeader("Token-ID", "SecurityInfo"))

        var bufferedCopy = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

        var sizeLog = string.Format("request message size: ~{0} KB", GetMessageLengthInKB(bufferedCopy.CreateMessage()));
        logger.Info(sizeLog);

        request = bufferedCopy.CreateMessage();
    }

    return null;
}

public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState) {
    if (logger.IsInfoEnabled) {
        // here I want to get the securityToken value ???

        var bufferedCopy = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

        var sizeLog = string.Format("response message size: ~{0} KB", GetMessageLengthInKB(bufferedCopy.CreateMessage()));
        logger.Info(sizeLog);

        reply = bufferedCopy.CreateMessage();
    }
}
```

> Any clue on how can I keep the **securityToken** variable so I can use it before sending the reply to the client?

Answer (score 0):

You can return your token in AfterReceiveRequest method (instead of returning null) and it will be passed to BeforeSendReply as correlationState object (cast it to appropriate type and you can use it)